# Bokeh Server callback from tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, bokeh

I'm kinda new on Python, and currently working on a interactive plot visualization using Bokeh where I need to show multiple related charts. To accomplish this i'm using bokeh server.

I've been reading the docs and [some examples](https://demo.bokehplots.com/) but i've been unable to find an example of a python callback (executed in the server) triggered by a selection on the plot. Basically what i would like to do is something like:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

TOOLS = "tap"
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]], y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]], name=['A', 'B']))

p.patches('x', 'y', source=source, color=["firebrick", "navy"], alpha=[0.8, 0.3], line_width=2)


def callback():
    print("TapTool callback executed on Patch {}")


??? <- some code here linking the taptool with the callback function defined above


curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

and then when executing the server and clicking on a patch:

> 2017-02-14 16:32:00,000 TapTool callback executed on Patch A

is this behavior something that can be achieved with bokeh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Edit from project maintainers.*

*There was some confusion and regressions around selections leading up to 1.0. For any post 1.0 version, for most use case you would now want to use a callback on the `'indices'` property of `selected`:*

```
source.selected.on_change('indices', callback)
```

*This kind of usage is now continuously and rigorously maintained under integration tests, and is what should be used for any post 1.0 Bokeh version.*

---

The `selected` event can be linked to an update function as follows:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

TOOLS = "tap"
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]],
                y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]], name=['A', 'B']))

pglyph = p.patches('x', 'y', source=source, color=["firebrick", "navy"],
                                alpha=[0.8, 0.3], line_width=2)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    # The index of the selected glyph is : new['1d']['indices'][0]
    patch_name =  source.data['name'][new['1d']['indices'][0]]
    print("TapTool callback executed on Patch {}".format(patch_name))

pglyph.data_source.on_change('selected',callback)

curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

**Update for newer Bokeh versions. Tested on version 0.12.16**

As [@Karel Marik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8126617/karel-marik) mentions glyphs can not mixed direct values assignment and `ColumnDataSource` at the same time. So the previous code does not work. Here is an update using only `source` which also includes code to print the multiple selections (made with shift + click):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

TOOLS = ["tap"]
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]],
    y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]],
    name=['A', 'B'],color=["firebrick", "navy"],
    alpha=[0.8,0.3],line_width=[3,3]))

pglyph = p.patches('x', 'y', color="color", alpha="alpha",
                   line_width="line_width", source=source)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    # The index of the selected glyph is : new['1d']['indices'][0]
    selections = new['1d']['indices']
    print("Number of selections:{}".format(len(selections)))
    for index in selections:
        patch_name =  source.data['name'][index]
        print("TapTool callback executed on Patch {}".format(patch_name))

pglyph.data_source.on_change('selected',callback)

curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

Comment: great! finnally got it working, thank you so much. could you explain how do you deduce that new['1d']['indices'][0] is the index of the selected glyph?

Comment: Well, I'm learning this stuff right now, so a lot of trial and error and looking into the examples from the bokeh GitHub repository. In this particular case, it helped printing variables while debugging,e.g. `print new`

Answer (score 1):

The solution published by Pablo is great but it doesn't work with recent bokeh version (0.12.13). I got an runtime error (*Supplying a user-defined data source AND iterable values to glyph methods is not possible*)

Following works for me ...

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

TOOLS = "tap"
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]], y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]], alphas = [0.8, 0.3], colors=["firebrick", "navy"], name=['A', 'B']))

pglyph = p.patches(xs='x', ys='y', source=source, line_width=2, alpha = 'alphas', color='colors')

def callback_fcn(attr, old, new):
    # The index of the selected glyph is : new['1d']['indices'][0]
    patch_name =  source.data['name'][new['1d']['indices'][0]]
    print("TapTool callback executed on Patch {}".format(patch_name))

pglyph.data_source.on_change('selected',callback_fcn)

curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

Comment: This works for the tap tool - any hints on how to do the same for the BoxSelectTool? I specifically do not want to get the selected glyphs but instead the x range of the box select...

Answer (score 1):

Since bokeh 0.13 the solution proposed by @Karel_Marik a needs small tweak:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

TOOLS = ["tap"]
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]],
    y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]],
    name=['A', 'B'],color=["firebrick", "navy"],
    alpha=[0.8,0.3],line_width=[3,3]))

pglyph = p.patches('x', 'y', color="color", alpha="alpha",
                   line_width="line_width", source=source)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    # The index of the selected glyph is : new['1d']['indices'][0]
    selections = new['1d']['indices']
    print("Number of selections:{}".format(len(selections)))
    for index in selections:
        patch_name =  source.data['name'][index]
        print("TapTool callback executed on Patch {}".format(patch_name))
```

<strike>pglyph.data_source.on_change('selected',callback)</strike>

```
pglyph.selected.on_change('indices', callback)

curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

I hope this helps somebody.