# Two Interactive Bokeh plots (II - with JSCallback )

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

So, I'm just linking the excellent post,
[Two interactive bokeh plots: select a value in one graph and change the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629103/two-interactive-bokeh-plots-select-a-value-in-one-graph-and-change-the-other/48629720#48629720)
with the additional question if/how can this be done standalone (no Bokeh server) i.e. just with JSCallbacks?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JS callback version for Standalone Document (tested on Bokeh 1.0.4):

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import numpy as np

source_bars = ColumnDataSource({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 1] , 'colnames': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
lines_y = [np.random.random(5) for i in range(3)]

plot1 = figure(tools = 'tap')
bars = plot1.vbar(x = 'x', top = 'y', source = source_bars, bottom = 0, width = 0.5)

plot2 = figure()
lines = plot2.line(x = 'x', y = 'y', source = ColumnDataSource({'x': np.arange(5), 'y': lines_y[0]}))
lines.visible = False

code = '''if (cb_data.source.selected.indices.length > 0){
            lines.visible = true;
            selected_index = cb_data.source.selected.indices[0];
            lines.data_source.data['y'] = lines_y[selected_index]
            lines.data_source.change.emit(); 
          }'''

plots = row(plot1, plot2)
plot1.select(TapTool).callback = CustomJS(args = {'lines': lines, 'lines_y': lines_y}, code = code)
show(plots)
```

Result:

[image]